# Is there any solution to position legend in chatjs without getting any error

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

Got the error whenever i switch the legend position from top to left or right.
code is given below:
the problem doesn't persist with the Line or Bar graph,the error occurs only for Doughnut graph.
sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-babbage-jvmclv

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3IS2.png)

```
import React from 'react'
import { Doughnut } from 'react-chartjs-2'
import {CategoryScale} from 'chart.js'; 
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto'
Chart.register(CategoryScale);

export default function DoughnutChart() {
    const data = [
        { year: 2010, count: 10 },
        { year: 2011, count: 20 },
        { year: 2012, count: 15 },
        { year: 2013, count: 25 },
      ];
    
  return (
    <Doughnut
        data={{
            labels: data.map(row => row.year),
            datasets: [
                {
                    data: data.map(row => row.count)
                }
            ],

        }}
        options={{
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            plugins: {
                legend: {
                    display: true,
                    position: 'top',
                    align: 'center',
                    labels: {
                       font: { size: 14 },
                       color: '#000;',
                       usePointStyle: true,
                       boxWidth: 20,
                       boxHeight: 7,
                    }
                 }
            }
        }}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: The code you posted seems OK and is unlikely to create any problems. You say that your problem occurs when you *change* the label position. I suppose you are changing the position programatically - the code that changes the position is probably the source of your problems. Please share a [full example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) possibly as a codesandbox or stackblitz link.

Comment: here the sandbox (try to change the position from top to left or right , you will get the error) :  https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-babbage-jvmclv

Comment: I see, I was wrong, there is an issue with just placing the legend to the left or to the right. Although I don't fully understand why this happens *only* in this particular context, I have a solution - the problem appears because chart.js expects the label *that is not a string* to be an array of strings to which it attempts to apply `reduce`. So the solution is to explicitly set the labels as strings through something like `labels: data.map((row) => ''+row.year)` or some other way to transform `year` number to string.

Comment: Thanks a lot kikon for the help. It's working now!!